# Missing conversation params when building Watson Assistant action with Node.js and Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-conversation, ibm-cloud-functions

I'm trying to build an IBM Chatbot using Watson Assistant and Node.js.
First, to get familiar with the ecosystem tried to make a very simple chatbot based on the sample app `text-bot-openwhisk`:

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/text-bot-openwhisk

I managed to recreate the dialog flow, the necessary actions and cloud functions and deploy them to the cloud.

I tried to make programmatic calls from a dialog node based on this article:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions

Basically I tried to duplicate the `getWeather.js` action of the aforementioned sample app.

The problem is the main function of the action doesn't receive the `conversation` property, so the `assert(params.conversation.context, 'params.conversation.context can not be null');` assertion always fires.

What should I change in order to receive the `conversation` params?

Comment: default the context to `{}` ?

Comment: The real problem is that the `conversation` parameter is missing so the whole dialog flow is broken for this action. As far as I now this parameter should always be passed to the action, so something is wrong here :)